# Loop through individual blocks within Concrete5

Tags: loops, block, area, concrete5

I have a Concrete5 template of which defines and outputs a content area:

```
$a = new Area('Content');
$a->display($c);
```

This outputs all the blocks within that content area, however what I want to loop through each block from that area and output it individually.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've figured this out myself, here's the code I used:

```
$blocksInArea = Page::getCurrentPage()->getBlocks('Content');

foreach ( $blocksInArea as $block ) {

    $this_block = Block::getByID($block->bID);
    $this_block->display();

}
```

Code adapted from [code on the C5 forums](http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/get-first-block-in-area-then-get-that-blocks-data/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a more efficient way to do this (more efficient than what you found in that forum post):

```
$blocks = $c->getBlocks('Content');
foreach ($blocks as $b) {
    $b->display();
}
```

Although I'm not sure why you'd want to do this -- calling `display($c)` on the area itself does the same thing.

One thing to note: this does not work properly if there are "Area Layouts" in that area. For that, you need to get more complicated... you can see how I've done this by looking at the code in my free "Page List Teasers" addon: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/page-list-teasers